# Animated Transitions with andreypopp/react-router-component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get this [react-router-component](http://andreypopp.viewdocs.io/react-router-component) to animate the transitions from one route to the next. I'd ideally like each "Location" component to be able to implement `componentWillEnter`, `componentWillLeave`, etc... function similar to the way you can with React's [Transition Groups](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html). Either by using TransitionGroups or just mimicking the behavior.

Has anyone played with this router like this before, or know of a similar router for React that can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/andreypopp/react-router-page-transition ?

Comment: I hadn't found that! That's exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: I've not used that component - but I'm guessing it must be adding/removing child components based on route somewhere.  So if you can find it and wrap it with <ReactCSSTransitionGroup /> you might be in business.